# Keyboard focus goes always to windows with "always on top"

Tags: 22.04, focus

After installing Ubuntu 22.04, I noticed this very annoying bug:

If a windows has set to "Always on top", when I switch active window with the TAB key, the new windows indeed gets the focus, but the keyboard focus goes to the windows always on top. No matter which window was active before or after TAB, keyboard focus will always go to the windows always on top.

Is there a way to make keyboard focus go to the newly active windows, as it was in every previous version?

The problem doesn't occur when the focus is transferred by a click.

Comment: I can confirm that in an Ubuntu 22.04 system in Boxes (default install). Very obvious bug indeed. This could be related to the mutter version.